# Tag synonyms outstanding

Tags: support

I notice we have 3 tag synonyms that are pending approval/voting/closing down.

https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms

It would be good if someone could approve or disapprove. A minor point really I guess.

Thanks

---

For people who aren't familiar with tag synonyms:

- You can vote on synonyms if you have 1250 reputation or more
- See [Help Center > Privileges > Create Tag Synonyms](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) for an explanation
- https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms lists all synonyms including suggested synonyms

For example, there's currently a suggestion that [buddhist-text](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buddhist-text) should be a synonym of [texts](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/texts).

The https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/tags/texts/synonyms page looks like this:

---

[image]

---

You can see, there, your opportunity to upvote or downvote that suggested synonym.

Comment: Why do you think that [tag:personal-practice] is a good tag to have? http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/ and http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/416/254 suggest maybe it isn't useful.

Comment: @ChrisW fair point. I've opened up another question on the personal-practice tag http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/1419/157 for further discussion if needed

Comment: Thank you, I think [the chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15162/buddhism) might be a better for 'discussion'.