# Using the chat room to discuss tags and retagging

Tags: discussion, tags, chat

As mentioned [here](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1418/tag-synonyms-outstanding#comment1664_1418) and [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19541472#19541472) I suggest we use the chat room (instead of meta) to discuss retagging.

I invite you to read and participate there if you're interested.